# The electricity _______

Tags: vocabulary, collocation

My questions is slightly different than the one suggested.

For my MA study I am working with oral messages produced by learners of English as a foreign language. So, while the most appropriate form would be ideal, there is a level of compromising sometimes.

I am trying hard to find a way for the following sentence to become adequate with as little intervention as possible. 
"and yesterday when I was doing the homework on my computer the **electricity shut down**."
I understand that replacing it with **there was a power cut/failure** would solve it. But are there any less intrusive possibilities, please?

***Edited: Well, I mean. I would like to capture (I know this is difficult) what the speaker meant pointing out errors, but not changing things unless they are needed. For instance, if I add there was to the sentence, as it was suggested by a colleague, that counts an an extra error the participant made. But in this case I don´t think you really need that. I know it sounds silly but it´ll impact on the results, and I don´t want to add extra unnecessary errors. I hope I made myself clear.

Thank you so much in advance.
R

Comment: There was a  temporary power  loss, or a power outage.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Does the electricity "go or cut" "off or out"?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/160378/does-the-electricity-go-or-cut-off-or-out)

Comment: Thanks, but not really. I am not asking for **THE** appropriate form, but what could be used instead to solve my issue still using as much as possible the discourse of my participant. Moreover, what would be acceptable as appropriate in oral English.

Comment: Please explain what you mean by *intrusive*.

Comment: Well, I mean. I would like to capture (I know this is difficult) what the speaker meant pointing out errors, but not changing things unless they are needed. For instance, if I add **there was** to the sentence, as it was suggested by a colleague, that counts an an extra error the participant made. But in this case I don´t think you really need that. I know it sounds silly but it´ll impact on the results, and I don´t want to add extra unnecessary errors. I hope I made myself clear. Thanks.

Comment: I would say "the electricity went down", but apparently that's far less common that I thought.

Comment: I think it would help if we knew for sure what the speaker meant. For example, there is a difference between electricity being "cut off" (prevented from being delivered), being "shut off" (implies it's no longer being produced and that this is intentional), and having "failed" (implying that something went wrong).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

yesterday when I was doing the homework on my computer the electricity **failed**

Compare to the following example sentence from [Linguistic Perspectives on English Grammar: A Guide for EFL Teachers](https://books.google.com/books?id=qP4nDwAAQBAJ&pg=PA251&lpg=PA251&dq=homework%20%22the%20%20electricity%20failed%22&source=bl&ots=ducBN7vCAN&sig=GefyJuMrcYTkPXTR6JmOCoCizr0&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjvn6CP9rbWAhVir1QKHe7cD4MQ6AEIMDAC#v=onepage&q=homework%20%22the%20%20electricity%20failed%22&f=false):

> She was doing the laundry when the electricity failed.

Comment: I thought of this answer myself. It's correct, but doesn't seem to be as common as some of the others,

Comment: Thank you, DavePhD! Even not being very common (agreed) this solves the issue perfectly.

Answer (score 15):

I am editing my comment to address the suggestions in the comments.

As the OP and many people mentioned, I would replace the whole sentence with

> ... there was a power outage
>
> ... we lost power

The goal is, however, to intervene as little as possible. In the given circumstances, I would use any of the following options.

> and yesterday when I was doing the homework on my computer the
> electricity (or power)
>
> - **cut out**
> - **went off**
> - **went out**

While @Acccumulation is right with his comment that **go off** may be confusing to English language learners, I completely disagree. The phrasal verb **go off**, according to the [Cambridge Dictionary](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/go-off), means the following:

> Stop Working
>
> - If a light or machine goes off, it stops working: *The lights went off in several parts of town because of the storm*
>
> Explode, or trigger
>
> - If a bomb goes off, it explodes: *The bomb went off at midday*
> - If a gun goes off, it fires: *His gun went off accidentally*
> - If a warning device goes off, it starts to ring loudly: *The alarm should go off automatically as soon as smoke is detected*

**Cut out** is typically used for electric equipment. For example, if you are on a plane and one of the engines cut out, you'll have to land with only one working. If an electric kettle cut out, this means it stopped boiling the water - either it broke down or the electricity supplied to it ceased for some reason.

**go out** is our clear favorite according to the comments and this [Google NGram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=electricity%20cut%20out%2Celectricity%20went%20off%2Celectricity%20went%20out%2Cpower%20went%20out%2C%20power%20went%20off%2C%20power%20cut%20out&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Celectricity%20cut%20out%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Celectricity%20went%20off%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Celectricity%20went%20out%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cpower%20went%20out%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cpower%20went%20off%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cpower%20cut%20out%3B%2Cc0) supplied by @Hellion. This is another phrasal verb with multiple different meanings according to the [Cambridge Dictionary](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/go-out)

> Leave
>
> - To leave a room or building: *Do you want to go out for a drink after work?
>
> Light / Fire
>
> - If a light or something that is burning goes out, it stops producing light or heat.

Finally, one could use **was cut off**, although it conveys a different meaning: the electricity cannot cut itself off - it was cut off by someone, perhaps power station personnel.

> I forgot to pay my power bill and the electricity was cut off.

Comment: [These Google Ngrams](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=electricity+cut+out%2Celectricity+went+off&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Celectricity%20cut%20out%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Celectricity%20went%20off%3B%2Cc0) show that 'went off' seems far more idiomatic; I'd strongly suspected this for the 'BrE' situation.

Comment: I had no idea Google Ngrams existed. Thanks a lot, Edwin!

Comment: I'm not a fan of "go off"; when an alarm goes off, that actually means it turns on. Seems like it could be confusing to English language learners.

Comment: I strongly prefer *went out*, and would use "power" instead of "electricity" with it.  ([Google NGrams](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=electricity+cut+out%2Celectricity+went+off%2Celectricity+went+out%2Cpower+went+out%2C+power+went+off%2C+power+cut+out&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Celectricity%20cut%20out%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Celectricity%20went%20off%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Celectricity%20went%20out%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cpower%20went%20out%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cpower%20went%20off%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cpower%20cut%20out%3B%2Cc0) agrees.)

Comment: also "went down" - When an electrical system goes down, it's not up and running.

Comment: I find "went out" the most idiomatic (AmE).

Comment: Thank you, everyone! I made big edits to my answer following your comments and recommendations!

Answer (score 3):

You could say "the electricity cut out".  Saying that it "shut down" isn't right, as it's the computer that shuts down, as a result of the lack of electricity.

Comment: Fully agree that the original is not correct, but I do think that the student meant to say that _the electricity_ "shut down", not the computer. (The more common meaning of computers shutting down seems coincidental but not intentional)

Comment: @Flater yes, I understand that.  I meant that it's not correct to say that "the electricity shut down" because "shut down" is a phrase more commonly used with machines, such as the computer, than with electricity itself.

Comment: I don't like your suggestion any more than "the electricity shut down", for the same reason: the electricity is the object, not the subject, of shutting down or cutting out (though cutting is more appropriate, as shutting down suggests a deliberate action as the cause).

Comment: @MarcvanLeeuwen as a BrE native speaker, "cut out" is definitely the natural phrase for me. I'm not sure why you talk about the electricity being the object/subject, that's entirely a matter of which phrasing you choose. In fact, I can't think of a phrasing where it's the object that doesn't imply somebody *intentionally* shut off the power, which is generally not the case in such events.

Comment: @Chris H  A breaker tripping or a power line being hit by a falling tree will cut the electricity; no human action, even less intention, is required. But electricity rarely cuts itself out.

Comment: @MarcvanLeeuwen yes, and if you know that it was a falling tree then saying that makes it clear. But without that being specified "the electricity was cut out" strongly implies (at least, to me) that it was an intentional act. I'm not suggesting electricity "cuts itself out"; it "cuts out". There's a gigantic difference between those two. To say it "cut itself out" would suggest agency, to say it "cut out" doesn't do that any more than saying it "stopped" or "failed".

Answer (score 3):

In British English, the uncommon word here is "electricity". Except in a technical context, you would normally use "power" instead.

"Shut down" also seems to have the wrong meaning. It usually implies that the shut-down was planned and deliberate, not (apparently) caused by some kind of accident or unpredictable failure.

The idiomatic phrases would be "the power failed" or "there was a power cut".

The phrase "the power *supply* failed" would usually suggest that the *computer's internal power supply circuit* had failed, not that there was no electricity supply to the building.

Note: we don't know what country the learner (or the OP) are from, but in the UK power cuts of more than a few minutes are extremely rare (i.e. they may not occur at a particular place for several years), and are usually predictable in advance to some extent since the cause is often bad weather conditions. The "normal" context for the EFL student's sentence might have been very different from this, of course.

Comment: I like the use of 'power' instead

Answer (score 1):

I'll offer simpler, more colloquial alternatives:

> Yesterday, I was doing my homework and the electricity just
>   ***went***.

and

> Yesterday, I was doing my homework and the power just
>   ***went***.

Pedants are free to ask where the electricity 'went' exactly, but simpler folk will take a dim view of that.

Comment: -1 **because** ??

Answer (score 0):

"While I was doing my homework, the building lost electrical power". Note that using "when" instead of "while" can give the impression of a causal relationship, e.g. "When drivers use cell phones, accident rates go up."

Comment: I'd go with just 'lost power' myself - keep it simple...